# Java Selenium 'Cannot resolve symbol Test' TestNG

Tags: selenium, testing, intellij-idea, automation, testng

I have a problem with TestNG. I cannot run a test.
I am getting this error:
[image]

POM.xml has no errors.

Here is the code in test page:

```
import Pages.SearchPage;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import core.Web.AllListeners.*;
    
    public class Search extends Listener {
    
        @Test(groups = "Regression")
        public void ticketBookingFunctionality() {
            new SearchPage()
                    .openUrl()
                    .inputCaption("Comic")
                    .selectCityByValue()
                    .inputDateFrom("2020-01-01")
                    .inputDateTo("2021-07-05")
                    .clickButtonSearch()
                    .clickButtonBuy()
                    .chooseTicket()
                    .choosePrice()
                    .pushButtonFindTickets()
                    .closeLoginPopup();
        }
    }
```

Where can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following [testng](/questions/tagged/testng) related jar files within your project.

[image: TestNG]